# Strip migration resources from entity framework assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I was wondering if there was a way to strip the generated resources of the entity framework migrations.

I have a project with about 400 migrations and now the generated dll size is about 25 MB. It seems that its the migrations resources that make most of the size.

It's not a big deal but when I publish this project online, I have to publish 3 instances (production, beta test and demo version). Each instance have 5 associated webjobs that depend on the big assembly.

So in total I have 6 * 3 * 25 = 450MB  to upload of data on a slow connection only for the migration.

If I could reduce the size of the assembly, the publish process would be faster.

Any idea ?

Comment: If your database is at reached large size and structure then I would recommend using a database project. I wasn't a fan till when I end up on a gargantuan database used by multiple webapi's where multiple develop teams impacted the database, the best feature is source control, and option to compare databases. Check in this link pro's and con's if you are interested: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/209815/sql-server-data-tools-entity-framework-is-there-any-synergy-here

Comment: What do you mean by "a database project" ?
A project in the solution where we only have the entity framework context migration and associated models ?
If this is the case, I'm already using this.

Comment: No, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWKllVyozOg, here is how you publish a database project https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/deploying-a-dacpac-with-sqlpackage/ with SqlPackage.exe